# Can primeng p-fileupload component handle return type out-of-the-box?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, primeng

I'm using primeng `p-fileupload` component to upload a single file.
Back-end API is `Spring Boot` that uploads file to `hdfs` and returns the path.
The file uploads fine but the `onUpload()` angular function is not called.
I know this is due to the returned path variable as with a `void` return type it works.
How can I get the path back with the default `p-fileupload` component (without having to write a custom upload function)?

```
<p-fileUpload name="file" url="http://<MY-IP>:8080/upload" accept=".csv" maxFileSize="1000000" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"></p-fileUpload>
```

```
onUpload(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      console.log(file);
      this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
      console.log(this.uploadedFiles);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

My `Spring Boot` API was returning a `String` instead of JSON.
Correct code returns `ResponseEntity` with a response object that has one variable called `path` (this is serialized to JSON under the hood).

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        final String path = fileUploadService.uploadFile(file, fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(new UploadFileResponse(path));
    }
```

In `Angular` can get returned JSON with `event.originalEvent.body.path`.

```
onUpload(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
        let path: string = event.originalEvent.body.path;
        console.log(path);
    }
}
```